# Pytorch: no CUDA-capable device is detected on Linux

Tags: pytorch, google-dl-platform

When trying to run some Pytorch code I get this error:

```
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp line=74 error=38 : no CUDA-capable device is detected
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "demo.py", line 173, in test
pca = torch.FloatTensor( np.load('../basics/U_lrw1.npy')[:,:6]).cuda()
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (38) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:74
```

I a running a cloud virtual machine using the 'Google Deep Learning VM'
Version: tf-gpu.1-13.m25
Based on: Debian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch) (GNU/Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64 x86_64\n)
Linux tf-gpu-interruptible 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1 (2019-04-12) x86_64

Environment info:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Sun May 26 05:32:33 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.72       Driver Version: 410.72       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   42C    P0    74W / 149W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

 $ echo $CUDA_PATH

 $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/nccl2/lib:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64

$ env | grep CUDA
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0

$ pip freeze
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.
7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
audioread==2.1.7
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.5
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
cloudpickle==1.1.1
cycler==0.10.0
dask==1.2.2
decorator==4.4.0
dlib==19.17.0
enum34==1.1.6
filelock==3.0.12
funcsigs==1.0.2
future==0.17.1
gdown==3.8.1
idna==2.8
joblib==0.13.2
kiwisolver==1.1.0
librosa==0.6.3
llvmlite==0.28.0
```

Comment: The torch error message: `no CUDA-capable device is detected` is telling you that current user doesn't have permissions to read or write from your shiny nvidia GPU.  A video card or GPU is usually owned by `root` by default.  Try running your program just once using `sudo`, or running as root temporally, and if that fixes, then you need to add the `video` group to your user, something like: `man useradd; useradd -a youruser video`.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the main reason for your problem. But I noticed one thing, GPU-Util 100%, while there are no processes running behind.

You can try out in the following directions.

1. sudo nvidia-smi -pm 1

which enables in persistence mode. This might solve your problem. The combination of ECC with non persistence mode can lead to 100% Utilization of GPU.

2. You can also disable ECC with the command nvidia -smi -e 0
3. Or best will be restart once again the whole process from the starting i.e reboot the Operating System once again.

Note: I'm not sure whether it will work for you or not. I had faced similar issue earlier so I am just telling based on my experience. 
Hope this will help you.